# org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager

Tags: java, gwt, jetty, tomcat8

I trying to upgrade my app to GWT 2.8 and Java 8 but no matter what I encounter with this problem. Note that I am using embedded Jetty.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(InstanceManagerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:32)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
```

Lots of the dependencies coming from GWT 2.8 but here is the pom.xml:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
<resources>
        <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vectomatic</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-gwt-file</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.asimalp.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>asimalp-commons</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.asimalp.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>asimalp-poi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-visualization</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.wsdl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.comm</groupId>
    <artifactId>comm</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc7</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain your enviroment - for instance if you are using Maven please share your pom.xml; how are you deploying, exact version of Tomcat where you are deploying the war and other relevant factors?

Comment: @RockyMM I am using Maven but I do not try to deploy anywhere I am just running dev mode on Eclipse. I will add pom to the original question.

Comment: are you sure this is the entire pom.xml? Usually there should be dependencies on gwt itself like, "gwt-user". Also, I don't see "gwt-maven-plugin". It might be that I missing something, but I am not sure how it used to work before :)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html), this is how quite similar to how I organized my project.

Comment: @RockyMM I use Eclipse GWT Plugin thats why there is no get-maven-plugin dependency on pom.xml.

Comment: Not sure that that is right. In any case, you won't be able to distribute your app once you would leave Eclipse. Try to add dependencies like the gwt-maven-plugin is suggestion and let's see if that is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a classloading issue. The following workaround worked for me: In the startup of your application force the two classes to be loaded. This way (I think) they are on the main classloader. I run this in a servlet that loads on startup of my application:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    loadClass("org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager");
    loadClass("org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager");
}

private void loadClass(String className) {
    try {
        Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cex) {}
}
```